# Nested Frames (WPF) - How to make outer frame's nav bar ignore inner frame?

Tags: .net, wpf

My application has a frame that is loaded/navigated when certain top-level buttons are clicked. The problem is, one of the hosted pages has a frame of it's own, and is messing with the outer frame's navigation bar (clicking back and forward navigates the inner frame, as well as the outer frame).

Is there any way to have the outer frame's navigation control only worry about its immediate contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's a frame property that handles this nicely:

```
ContentFrame.JournalOwnership = JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal;
```

Setting this on the inner frame forces it to use its own journal, rather than using the default (JournalOwnership.Automatic, which is the same as JournalOwnership.UsesParentJournal if the frame is hosted in either another Frame or a NavigationWindow).